# How to create JSON output to be used with jquery ui autocomplete?

Tags: json, jquery-ui, google-app-engine

[Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=bi) is sample json reply needed for jquery ui autocomplete. Looks like only `label` and `value` are needed in my case.

I have the following code:

```
class City(db.Model):
  '''Storage for cities ids.

  Index
    key_name: id of the city
    parent:   Country of the city
  '''
  city_name = db.StringProperty()

term = self.request.get('term')
query = City.all()
query.filter('city_name >=', term)
query.filter('city_name <=', unicode(term) + u"\ufffd")
cities = query.fetch(20, 0)
```

How to format result as json in the format like value = city_name, id = key_name?

I've also seen the following code somewhere, but it doesn't work for me:

```
map(lambda x: x.city_name(), cities)
```

Comment: I hate to be rude, but you're asking an awful lot of straightforward questions that have lots of docs and demo code. Have you tried looking for existing examples of what you're trying to do elsewhere? Searching for "app engine python JSON", for instance, would lead you straight to instructions on how to parse and output JSON in App Engine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use simplejson which is included in django.utils:

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json
```

Then create an array of dictionaries and json encode it:

```
city_array = []
for city in cities:
  city_array.append({'value': city.city_name, 
                     'label': city.city_name,
                     'id': city.key().name()})

json_message = json.dumps(city_array)
```